# App crashes at startup Couldn't load flutter from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader

Tags: flutter

After installing and running flutter app, it crashes and I get these error for released app in logcat of android studio.

```
2023-04-29 15:11:22.392 14761-14761 FlutterLoader           pid-14761                            E  Flutter initialization failed.
                                                                                                    java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load flutter from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/my.package.name-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/my.package.name-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]]: findLibrary returned null
                                                                                                        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:93)
                                                                                                        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:163)
                                                                                                        at s2.d.e()
                                                                                                        at io.flutter.embedding.engine.a.<init>()
                                                                                                        at io.flutter.embedding.engine.a.<init>()
                                                                                                        at io.flutter.embedding.android.e.G()
                                                                                                        at io.flutter.embedding.android.e.p()
                                                                                                        at io.flutter.embedding.android.d.onCreate()
                                                                                                        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5619)
                                                                                                        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2512)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2607)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:174)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1325)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5756)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
                                                                                                        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                                                    Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load flutter from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/my.package.name-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/my.package.name-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]]: findLibrary returned null
                                                                                                        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:358)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:526)
                                                                                                        at io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterJNI.loadLibrary()
                                                                                                        at s2.d$a.b()
                                                                                                        at s2.d$a.call()
                                                                                                        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                                                                                                        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
                                                                                                        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

these logs happen in api 19

I can run and debug app with android studio in this device but the released app is stopping in this device.
Can any one help me to solve this?

Comment: Is support for multidex enabled? Also, flutter currently doesn't support the x86 for Android. So, if you are testing on that architecture, it will throw the error. This error doesn't occur in debug mode because in debug mode the code is compiled in jit. Also see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android

Comment: Multidex is not enabled since I've never encountered multidex warning so my codes are below 64k methods

Comment: What is the architecture of the device you are testing on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case the error was because of installing wrong apk in the device with command line. if the device has armeabi-v7a architecture, then you should install armeabi-v7a.apk and so on for other architectures.

Answer (score 0):

Run flutter doctor in powershell.

Comment: Then how will help to solve the problem??